# How many objects are created after String concatenation using '+' operator?

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

I want to ask that how many objects are created after execution of the following statement in java..

```
String str = "a"+"b"+"c"+"d"
```

In my opinion, only one object should get created and that of StringBuilder. Please correct me and explain the logic behind it..thanks in advance.

Comment: You are creating a single object of type `String`. There is no `StringBuilder` in your line of code...

Comment: I got to know that this code would get internally changed something like new StringBuilder().append("a").append("b").append("c").append("d")...that's why I think the answer should be 1

Comment: @deHaar if the assignment to string reference is `literal` string , object will not be created. because all will be string pooled.

Comment: @TheScientificMethod thanks, didn't know that and just commented about the code, not the internals...

Answer (score 10):

The simple answer is zero objects.  That is a compile time constant expression, and the bytecode compiler evaluates it to `"abcd"` ... before creating the ".class" file.

Actually, with modern JVMs, the instantiation of `String` objects associated with literals and compile time constant expressions is lazy, so a single `String` object may be created the first time that statement is executed.  But only the *first* time.

So a *more correct* answer is either zero or one `String` objects, depending on:

- the JVM implementation of string literal interning (lazy or eager), and
- whether this is the first execution of any statement that uses the `"abcd"` literal or compile time constant.

Then there is the possibility that the statement might be optimized away by the JIT compiler if `str` is never accessed.

And it gets even more complicated if you consider the possibility of class unloading.

Comment: If "abcd" is evaluated..wouldn't the compiler make an Object of it?

Comment: It won't make an object **when the statement is executed**!

Comment: can you mention an example of a modern JVM?

Comment: So the exact answer for the question is 0 or 1, right?

Comment: Java 11 ... of course.   I'm not sure when the instantiation of String objects was made lazy, and it is too much work to check.

Comment: It means while execution it will create an object..right?

Comment: @Maxim - strictly speaking, the answer is "zero or, or either zero or one, depending on the Java version".  It depends on what strategy the JVM uses for instantiating literal String objects.

Comment: @AbhishekJain - Not correct.  It means that execution **might** create the String object.

Comment: I think there is a chance that the string can be evicted from the string pool after some period of time if the application intensively works with unique strings.

Comment: Don't we consider the String pool constants as object?

Comment: @Maxim - Actually, when a String object corresponding to a literal is added to the string pool, there will be additional references to the object associated with the class or classes that "mention" it in the code.  Those references will prevent the String object from being evicted from the pool ... unless the classes themselves are garbage collected.  And that won't happen unless you are doing dynamic class loading.

Comment: @StephenC Interesting! I will try to write a code which generates all possible combinations of characters, let say up to 100. This should cause OutOfMemory exception.

Comment: Ummm ... I said "when a String object **corresponding to a literal** is added to the string pool".  If you simply generate lots of (non-literal) strings programmatically and intern them, then ... yes ... they will be evicted from the pool if the heap gets sufficiently full.  The difference is that those objects won't be strongly reachable.

Comment: As another aspect, when you disable the interpreter, the just-in-time compiler may eliminate the entire statement as there is no actual use of `str`, even before its first execution, so no string will be created. Also, if another code used the literal `"abcd" before, no string will be created by the statement, as it will reuse the instance from the pool.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could disable the interpreter.  Your second point is already covered.